# Find the value of $(r_1-r)(r_2-r_3)$

Tags: triangles

$$=(\frac {\Delta}{s-a}-\frac{\Delta}{s})(\frac{\Delta}{s-b}-\frac{\Delta}{s-c})$$
$$=\Delta ^2(a)(b-c)\frac {1}{\Delta ^2}$$
$$a(b-c)$$

But the answer given is $a^2$

**$r_1,r_2, r_3$ are the ex radii on sides a, b and c respectively.**

Comment: Your result $a(b-c)$ looks right to me... What's the source of the problem?

Comment: If source means the place where I got the question from, then i don’t know, because I got it from cousin who was having trouble solving it.

Comment: Oh... I see. Well, as said, your proceeding looks right. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s*%28s-a%29%28s-b%29%28s-c%29*%281%2F%28s-a%29-1%2Fs%29*%281%2F%28s-b%29-1%2F%28s-c%29%29) confirms so